# Formatar o Excel de saída - Python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel

Transformo uma lista em um Dataframe e mando para um Excel, está funcionando direitinho. Segue o código:

```
Df = pd.DataFrame(Lista, columns = colunas_geradas)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Exemplo.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
Df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Teste', index = False)
writer.save()
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível formatar o Excel no código. Por exemplo: Mudar a cor dos Nomes das Colunas, arrumar o tamanho das cédulas, adicionar uma imagem, coisas assim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A biblioteca pandas possui um guia sobre [como trabalhar com estilos](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html), mas avisam que é uma funcionalidade nova, implementada a partir da versão 0.17.1.

Nesse link que te providenciei você encontra snippets de código para pintar, criar gráficos, alterar cores dos conteúdos das células, entre outros.

---

**Mudar a cor dos nomes das colunas:** acredito que não seja possível.

**Arrumar o tamanho das células:** acredito que não, no entanto, encontrei [este tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326973/is-there-a-way-to-auto-adjust-excel-column-widths-with-pandas-excelwriter) que ensina uma alternativa para alterar o tamanho das células utilizando (mais ou menos) a biblioteca pandas.

**Adicionar uma imagem:** é possível usando a xlsxwriter, como mostrado [neste tópico](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_images.html).

---

Além da biblioteca pandas, conheço outras duas bibliotecas que te permitem manipular planilhas:

- [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/), como dito acima
- [exemplo utilizando pandas](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.i/example_pandas_conditional.html)

E a biblioteca [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/), que também tem um tópico só pra falar sobre [como trabalhar com pandas](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/pandas.html) e um tópico ensinando um pouco sobre [como trabalhar com estilos](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/styles.html).

---

Além dessas bibliotecas, deixo esse link que achei extremamente informativo:
[Improving Pandas Excel Output](http://pbpython.com/improve-pandas-excel-output.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sim, possui formas, eu costumo formata-las assim:

```py
from win32com.client import Dispatch                           
xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xlsPath = ('diretório do arquivo.xlxs')
wb = xl.Workbooks.open(absPath)
ws = wb.Worksheets(1).Select()
ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

ws.Range("A1").Font.Bold = True #Fonte em Negrito
ws.Range("A1:AF200").Font.Size = 10 #Tamanho da Fonte das células informadas
ws.Range("A1:G1").Merge(False) #Mesclar as células
ws.Range("A1",letra_total_coluna + "1").Interior.ColorIndex = 15 #Colorir o interior das celulas
```